# How to ensure that the request has been sent before manually reading the cache?

Tags: rtk-query

Like this example: [constructing-a-dynamic-base-url-using-redux-state](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#constructing-a-dynamic-base-url-using-redux-state), I need to get the data of a certain endpoint from the cache to build fetch arg, I can get the data by `api.endpoints.getPost.select(postId)(getState())`, But how do I ensure that the getPost request has been sent?

```js
const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPost: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `/posts/${id}`,
    }),
    getBook: builder.query({
      async queryFn(postId, { dispatch, getState }) {
        // could I use this?
        await dispatch(api.endpoints.getPost.initiate(postId))
        const { data: post } = api.endpoints.getPost.select(postId)(getState())
        // ...
        // use post.xxx to fetch books...
        myFetch(`/books/${post.xxx}`)
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current RTK 1.7 beta you can just `const result = await dispatch(api.endpoints.getPost.initiate(postId)).unwrap()`.

But what you are doing here generally looks very dangerous. There is no mechanism in place that will re-run `getBook` after `getPost` returns a different result in the future. Things will probably get out of sync this way.

Dependent queries should probably better be handled in a custom hook with two `useQuery` hook calls, where the second hook call gets a part of the result from the first call as an argument.